# How do I get a list the comment types' machine name?

Tags: 9, comments

Drupal ships with just one comment type enabled, with the machine name `comment`. But if the **Forum** module is installed, there is also `comment_forum`. And site builders can define new comment types in the GUI.

How do I get a list the comment types' machine name? Or: How can I get all comments, regardless of name.

Comment: As in, with the Entity API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comment types are an entity type, so you can load them as with any entity type, and get the machine name from [CommentType::id()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityBase.php/function/EntityBase%3A%3Aid/9.3.x):

```
$comment_types = array_map(
  function ($comment_type) {
    return $comment_type->id();
  },
  \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('comment_type')->loadMultiple()
);
```

Or to load all comments, regardless of type, you can use:

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('comment')->loadMultiple()
```